# Upload file In MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, razor

I need an action to create `MyModel` type with some fields and also some files to upload to DB. So this is a part of my View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {

<fieldset>
 <dl>
    <dt>
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
</dt>
<dd>
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</dd>
    <dt>
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NeededFiles)
</dt>
    <dd>
@foreach(var item in Model.NeededFiles) { 
 <div style="margin:5px;">
       @Html.Label(item.Title)
       <input type="file" name="@item.Name" />
 </div>
}
     </dl>
 </fieldset>
 <input type="submit" value="Create" class="button red" />
}
```

But in post Action I have some problem to get file Path:
This is my Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyModel ViewModel FormCollection collection, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) {

 //....
 }
```

`Request.Files` is `null` so I can't use it and I don't know why. also files `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` is null. then I try to get from `FormCollection` 
so I use this:

```
   string filePath = collection.GetValue(item.Name).AttemptedValue;
```

but `filePath` just returned file Name not File path, I don't understand. when I choose file I can see all path in input but when I want to get it just file Name returned. where is my problem? what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the enctype to multipart/form-data on your form tag? I cant see it there...

Once you've done that, have a look at this:

[Trying to upload a file with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718400/trying-to-upload-a-file-with-asp-net-mvc)

That should cover your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your view to include multipart/form-data:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } )) {
   //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing on

@using(Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } )) { 
   //.... 
}

Check out-
http://hozefam.com/post/2012/08/10/Exploring-File-Upload-and-Download-in-MVC-3.aspx